# CSS responsive Grid not responding

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-grid

I am trying to build a responsive web site with a trivial two-column layout, navigation in the left column followed by content in the next section. The problem is that I haven't yet found the CSS to make the content section drop below the menu on narrow screens.

The menu section is fixed at 15rem - that part works ok.

The main section remains firmly fixed to the right of the menu (causing overflow) no matter what I've tried.

Here's the relevant CSS ...

```
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 15rem repeat(auto-fit, minmax(30ch, 1fr)) ;
  gap: 0;
  margin: auto auto;
  }
```

Here's where the top-level markup (produced in php) is created ...

```
function sPageContent () {
    $sData ='';
    $sData.='<!DOCTYPE html>';
    $sData.='<HTML lang="en-GB">';
    $sData.='<HEAD>'.sDocHead().'</HEAD>';
    $sData.='<BODY>';
//    $sData.='  <header>'.sPageHeading().'</header>';
    $sData.='  <nav>'.sSiteMenu().'</nav>';
    $sData.='  <main>'.sContent().'</main>';
//    $sData.='  <aside>'.sAnnounce().'</aside>';
//    $sData.='  <footer>'.sPageFooter().'</footer>';
    $sData.='</BODY>';
    $sData.='</HTML>';
    return $sData;
    }
```

I can add more detail (or a screen-shot) if required.

You'll notice I've inhibited header/footer in case they were interfering.

I'd be grateful for any insight into what I'm missing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a media query to accomplish what you want.  Following the principle of mobile-first, the base styles apply in the mobile view and the media-query specifies what happens after the viewport reaches a minimum width.

Run the snippet below and choose the "Full page" option to see how the grid behaves at different sizes.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: min-content auto min-content;
}

header {
  background: skyblue;
}

main {
  background: orange;
}

footer {
  background: yellowgreen;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 30em) {
  body {
    grid-template-columns: 15em 1fr;
    grid-auto-rows: auto min-content;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>Menu</nav>
</header>
<main>Main Content</main>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

Comment: Brilliant ... worked first time, thank you.

I was hoping to avoid a media query but for now I have a site that seems to work ok (for acceptable values of "work") and I can research alternatives at my leisure.